# How to define keywords starting by '*' following by words in syntax file

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want to enable syntax highlighting for Calculix simulation software. The input text file is made of keywords starting by '*', such as `*HEADING` or `NO ANALYSIS`. The keyword starts the line and there can be only one per line. This file is usually edited by hand, with all misspelling I can do. Two typical line formats can be:

```
*HEADING
*AMPLITUDE, NAME=x20, TIME=TOTAL TIME
```

I want to highlight as keyword the exact keyword including '*' so I cannot use Abaqus syntax provided by Vim. So far, I have read the vim help file that I don't entirely understand, and I tried the following:

1. Brute force.
   I can make it works including spaced keywords with:

   ```
   syntax match ccxKeyword '\*END STEP'
   highlight link ccxKeyword Statement
   ```

   Problem: I can have only 1 keyword per line and I have 100+ keywords. It is a nightmare to maintain and not efficient. I would prefer a better solution.
2. Regions.
   I tried to take an example with HTML syntax but there is a closing element for tags which Calculix does not have. Either the region end is `$`, or it's `,`, but I cannot have both...

I understand, the ideal solution would be: a regex identifying the keyword '^*[a name of a keyword list]'. The list contains all keywords with a non spaced separator. Is it possible? Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Re maintenance and efficiency, have you look at some of the syntax files shipped with vim? They often have long keyword lists in addition to other things. You could try `syntax iskeyword` with a setting that includes the asterisk, and then use `syntax keyword` instead of match.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You mean `syntax iskeyword=@,42,48-57,_,192-255` `syntax keyword ccxKeyword *AMPLITUDE`

Comment: Assuming 42 is char2nr('*')? The option syntax allows characters, which is far more readable… but yes effectively. You can list more than one keyword that way, too, if that matters. Let me know if that solves your problem

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes char 42 is * in ASCII table. It does not solve the issue. I also tried  `syntax iskeyword+=*` but it does not work either...

Comment: This works for me: `set iskeyword=@,42,48-57,_,192-255`, `syn keyword mykeyword *HEADING *AMPLITUDE`, `hi link mykeyword Statement`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt. It works ! Thanks. But I cannot accept your answer there is no check icon...